# select-all options in a optgroup

Tags: javascript, html

I have a parent option list as shown below , all I want to do is when user select the parent option all the child options should be selected. how can I do that ? Is it possible to give the all child values in the parent option ?

```
 <html><head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .optionGroup
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:italic;
    }

.optionChild
{
    padding-left:15px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<select multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Parent0" class="optionGroup">Parent Tag</option>
      <option value="child1" class="optionChild">Child Tag</option>
      <option value="child2" class="optionChild">Child Tag</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many ways to do that, but if the list is big, it's quite a bit of work. If you are able to change the source, there is an easier way.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
   <option value="Parent0" class="optionGroup parent0">
   <option value="child2" class="optionGroup parent0">
   <option value="child1" class="optionGroup parent0">
   <option value="Parent1" class="optionGroup parent1">
   <option value="child2" class="optionGroup parent1">
   <option value="child1" class="optionGroup parent1">
</select>
```

Now, you simply select every option that has the same class as the parent (parent0, parent1) etc. This would be much easier with jQuery. Are you using only javascript?

Comment: And, if you're able to use HTML 5, you can use a data-group="p0" pattern so you don't have to share the class attribute

Comment: is it possible to give all the values to the parent option ?

Comment: Yes. You could do that too. <option value="Parent0" class="optionGroup child1 child2"> Then, you look at all your classes and find the options that have that value. But again, it's a lot of work. You should consider jQuery or something similar. That's what it was built for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you use a tree selection instead of a multiselect for your requirement.
please check below link for example
https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/